# Updating Core Data fail

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data

```
-(void)passDataBack:(PersonHolder *)contact{
    NSFetchRequest *request = [NSFetchRequest fetchRequestWithEntityName:@"Person"];
    NSPredicate *predicate = [NSPredicate predicateWithFormat:@"firstName == %@",contact.firstName];
    [request setPredicate:predicate];
    NSError *error;
    Person *person = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]lastObject];
    [person.firstName setValue:contact.firstName forKey:@"fistName"];
    [person.lastName setValue:contact.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];

    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){

        NSLog(@"Could not save edited data");
    }

}
```

during runtime I can see that `contact` is loaded with all the data I'm passing through but my person entity is not getting updated.

I saw the answer [how to update core data entered values](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053117/how-to-update-core-data-entered-values) and I think I am certainly missing something

Comment: Person *person = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]lastObject]; --> check error

Comment: Your code for updating the `person` object seems wrong.  Why are you updating a `fistName` (sic) property of the `firstName` property using KVC?  Same for `lastName`?

Comment: @vaibby error is nil

Comment: error is nil . Wait what is sic? firstName is the attribute and I'm using the value in contact.firstName.

Comment: using person.firstName = contact.firstName doesn't work either. person.firstName is showing nil at run time.

Answer (score 0):

You don't missing something, quite the contrary

The Core Data equivalent to the simple property setter

```
person.firstName = contact.firstName
```

is

```
[person setValue:contact.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[person setValue:contact.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
```

consider also the typo `@"fistName"`

**Edit:** Try this syntax

```
NSArray *people = [self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error];
if (error) {
    NSLog(@"%@", error);
    return;
}
if (people.count) {
    Person *person = [people lastObject];
    person.firstName = contact.firstName;
    person.lastName = contact.lastName;

    if(![self.managedObjectContext save:&error]){
       NSLog(@"Could not save edited data");
    }
} else {
    NSLog(@"result array is empty"):
}
```

Comment: Is the array returned from the fetch request empty? Just calling `lastObject` on an empty array returns `nil`

Comment: well its showing  0x0 for every field( i don't know what they are called) just see the link <http://postimg.org/image/z1gvxwzgr/>

Comment: I updated the answer to suggest a more reliable syntax

Comment: I screwed up my predicate method. I'm comparing the old value with the new updated value in `contact` so they will never match.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of

```
[person.firstName setValue:contact.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[person.lastName setValue:contact.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
```

use

```
[person setValue:contact.firstName forKey:@"firstName"];
[person setValue:contact.lastName forKey:@"lastName"];
```

or

```
person.firstName = contact.firstName;
person.lastName = contact.lastName;
```

Edit : a suggestion before blindly assigning last object of fetch query to person object and setting values in core data, check if your fetch query returns a result or not. This may crash.

```
NSArray *persons = [[[CoreDataManager sharedManager] context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error]; 

if(persons.count > 0){
 // do changes in the object
 } 
else{ 
// do what you want to do to handle this situation 
}
```

Comment: check if you are getting person entity here 
Person *person = [[self.managedObjectContext executeFetchRequest:request error:&error]lastObject];

Comment: well that is nil. Why? What happened here?

Comment: thats the issue. thats why its not getting updated.
Now check is there any entry in your database that satisfy the predicate.
Chances are that there is not such entry.

Comment: NSArray *persons = [[[CoreDataManager sharedManager] context] executeFetchRequest:fetchRequest error:&error];

if(persons.count > 0){
// do changes 
}
else{
// do what you want to do to handle this situation
}

Comment: oh my god . shit . I just realised. I am always changing the first name in editing but its sending the updated name back which means the original name and updated name will not match ever. Now am at a loss on how to update any of my field. Because is case I update all my field I wont be able compare any of the data with the original data. What can I do?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97977/discussion-between-rohit-and-rishab).