# Reload Entire Core Data Object Rather than Add Specific Data

Tags: ios, core-data

I am very new to iOS. I am completely new to Core Data. I am taking over the code base of a project from my professor's former grad students.

When my app fetches an image from its database, the path to the img is this:

```
/Users/matt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA58E774-84BE-48F6-B50F-5921F682E87B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA30DEFB-D90B-4D52-8462-3F8A5F4C55ED/Leaflet-US.app/thumbnail/species/Abies fraseri/images/LTV-BAM-2848_crop.jpg
```

Because `CoreSimulator/Devices` is included in the path, I assume it looks for the image in the app's Core Data. I could be mistake, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

I also have a version of thumbnail in my app's Resources file, which you can see does contain the `Abies fraseri` directory.

[image]

Right now, the Core Data does not have the `Abies fraseri` directory. I know this because in terminal I can `cd` into `/Users/matt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA58E774-84BE-48F6-B50F-5921F682E87B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/DA30DEFB-D90B-4D52-8462-3F8A5F4C55ED/Leaflet-US.app/thumbnail/species/` and verify that `Abies fraseri` does not exist. I would like to update the core data's version of `thumbnail/species` so that it has it.

From what I've [seen](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41040253/how-to-use-coredata-in-xcode-8-with-objective-c) [in](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19053117/how-to-update-core-data-entered-values) these posts, you update an object of core data by adding specific key/value pair to the array that results from a fetch.

Example:

```
NSManagedObject *entityNameObj = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"EntityName" inManagedObjectContext:context];
[entityNameObj setValue:@"someValue" forKey:@"someKey"];
```

However, is there a way to delete and re-enter thumbnail, rather than have to go through and specify each new key value pairs? I ask because I updated the local db, thumbnail, with 200 new species, each of which is a directory with several images.

The fetch request, if it applies:

```
    NSFetchRequest *fetchRequest = [[NSFetchRequest alloc] init];
    NSManagedObjectContext* context = [(LeafletAppDelegate*)[[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate] managedObjectContext];
    NSEntityDescription *entity = [NSEntityDescription entityForName:@"Species" inManagedObjectContext:context] ;
    [fetchRequest setEntity:entity];


    if (predicate)
    {
        [fetchRequest setPredicate:predicate];
    }

    [fetchRequest setSortDescriptors:sortDescriptors];

    // Create and initialize the fetch results controller.
    NSFetchedResultsController *aFetchedResultsController = [[NSFetchedResultsController alloc] initWithFetchRequest:fetchRequest managedObjectContext:context sectionNameKeyPath:sectionNameKeyPath cacheName:nil];

    self.fetchedResultsController = aFetchedResultsController;
    fetchedResultsController.delegate = self;

    // Memory management.
    [aFetchedResultsController release];
    [fetchRequest release];

    return fetchedResultsController;
```

Comment: What do you mean by "update the entire Core Data?"

Comment: I have a folder named "thumbnail" in my app's code. It serves as my local database and I can change it in Finder. However, there is also a version of thumbnail that is core data, its in `/Users/matt/Library/Developer/CoreSimulator/Devices/DA58E774-84BE-48F6-B50F-5921F682E87B/data/Containers/Bundle/Application/.....`. I'd like to update the core data version to be identical to the one I have in my project's files.

Comment: I'm with @yoninja because I still can't tell what you're trying to do here.

Comment: @TomHarrington I reworded most of the post in an attempt to make it more comprehensible!

Comment: @TomHarrington, have you solved this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Because CoreSimulator/Devices is included in the path, I assume it looks for the image in the app's Core Data. I could be mistake, so please correct me if I'm wrong.

You're mistaken. Nothing goes into Core Data unless you make specific Core Data calls to save the data there. "CoreSimulator" in the path means that you're looking at files used by the simulator and has nothing at all to do with whether you're using Core Data. As a result-- the parts of your code about doing fetch requests are not useful, unless you also have other code that saves to Core Data that you haven't mentioned. You haven't put anything in Core Data, therefore there's nothing to fetch.

> I also have a version of thumbnail in my app's Resources file, which you can see does contain the Abies fraseri directory.

We actually can't. What that screenshot shows is that it's present in the Xcode project. That doesn't necessarily mean it's included in the app when you build it. It's possible to have files in the project that aren't part of the build. There are various reasons for that, including projects that have multiple targets that don't include all of the same files (for example an app and an app extension).

But it's also possible to leave files out of a target by accident, and that's a likely cause of your problem. Select the images in question and open up Xcode's file inspector on the right side of the window. Look in the "target membership" section and make sure there's a check mark next to the app target.

Another possibility-- less likely but not impossible-- is that you're just looking in the wrong place. Xcode supports many different simulators, all of which are independent of the others. It's possible that you're building for one simulator but checking the file path for a different one. For example, maybe you're building for an iPhone 7 simulator but looking at file paths for the iPhone SE simulator. The files aren't shared so updating one doesn't affect the others.

Regardless of the actual cause, it appears that your problem comes down to one of file management and has nothing to do with Core Data-- again, unless you have other code that writes to Core Data that you haven't mentioned or shared.